# What is the function of "<>" code in JAVA?

Tags: java, generics

I am still learning JAVA. I often met JAVA code something like this :

```
....
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
....
ComboBox<String> var;
....
```

Can someone tell me the usage of that code?

Thank you, Harpan.

Comment: This subject is too broad to put it in one simple answer. Google `generics`. Or nvm, here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: I have search google "java <>" or something like that and google didnt tell me anything. If I know it called generics, I will search google "java generics". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`<? extends Boolean>` means any class that extends the `Boolean` class can be used here. Let's say you have

```
class MyBoolean extends Boolean {
...
}
```

Then this `MyBoolean` class can be used instead of  `<? extends Boolean>`

Essentially you could call the `changed` function like the following

```
ObservableValue<MyBoolean> observable = new ObservableValue<MyBoolean>();
changed(observable ,true, false);
```

Comment: That would be great, but the `Boolean` class is final.

Comment: @Obicere `java.lang.Boolean` is final; the OP's example could have been another `Boolean`. A less ambiguous example would probably be better for this answer.

Comment: Yes .. i was going to say the same thing as @Jason C

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Generics in java.
Let me try to explain this in short.
**Before Generics:**

```
List colourList = new ArrayList();
```

this colourList can holds any object.

**With Generics:**
Example: `List<String> colourList = new ArrayList<String>();`
here colourList  is a List which can holds only String Type as its item.
The generic type definition will have a placeholder for a type. We supply a class/type as parameter for placeholder and create a new object for a generic type.

Or we can also user Wildcard (?) in place of place holder
Example:

```
public static List<?> topFive(List<?> list) {
    return list.subList(0, 5);
  }
```

Here we can pass any type of list.

Hope this may be useful for you.